# Inverse Laplace transform of e^(svt)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, laplace-transform

What is the inverse Laplace transform of $e^{svx}+ e^{-svx}$, where v is a parameter?

Comment: It seems ambiguous. In general one have a function of $t$, $f(t)$, which is transformed to a function of $s$, $F(s)$. Here there are both $s$ and $t$. What are $s$ and $t$?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify: I was solving a PDE involving two variables, (x, t) and applied the Laplace transform with respect to x

Comment: I changed the variable so it shouldn't appear ambiguous anymore

Comment: CAS says: $\delta (t-v x)+\delta (t+v x)$

Comment: Is that Dirac's delta function? How did you do it?